# Determine if graph is complete from degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

If I have a simple graph with degree sequence

1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7

How can I determine if it is complete?

I realize I could draw it, but I need to evaluate a large graph in a computer program and determine if it is complete or not.

Comment: Do you mean 'connected', not 'complete'? If so, you want either the Havel-Hakimi or Erdős–Gallai theorems

Answer (score 2):

The question must be wrong. A complete graph on $n$ vertices has degree sequence $n-1, n-1,..., n-1.$ That is, each vertex has degree equals to $n-1.$